# Yii2 - Load fixtures from different modules at once

Tags: yii2, fixtures

I have fixtures in several modules, and I want to be able to load them at once. The fixtures are in modules with the following namespaces:

```
backend\modules\currency\fixtures
backend\modules\invoiceType\fixtures
backend\modules\unit\fixtures
...
```

I know i can load fixture from a module with this command;

```
yii fixture * --namespace=backend\modules\currency\fixtures
```

Also I know i can put all namespaces in `globalFixtures` but i don't think this is the proper way.

Is there any way i can make some configuration, so I can load all fixtures from all specified modules at once?

Basically I am looking for something analogous to `migrationPath` for migrations, but to be available for fixtures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you have 3 ways of doing this.

### Use `globalFixtures`

I don't see anything wrong in this. This functionality was made for exactly this.

### Write a custom script

You can write a custom script to run several times `yii fixture * --namespace=` with some configuration array.

### Use dependencies

You can create a main fixture or choose one to be the main one and have it depend on all the others using `yii\test\Fixture::$depends` property. You can read more on the documentation page [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/test-fixtures). Just look where they give an example of using `$depends`.

Hope some of this will help you.

Comment: globalFixtures are always executed, and i'm not able to run only fixtures in given module. "Write a custom script" - that's what i am doing now but i have to handle dependencies on my own. if two modules require same dependency they are going to be executed twice. Maybe dependencies with "main" fixture is the way to go.

Comment: @tsanchev The script one is easier to implement, but I believe dependencies is the way to go. I meant either create a new main one or choose one of the existing to be the main one and have it depend on all others. There is no sense in everything depending on everything.

Comment: i'm going to address this issue with the yii team because this is more general "problem" the same question goes not only to fixtures but also for tests, i.e. how to run all tests from all modules :) i think there should be consistent way of handling migrations, fixtures, tests that are inside modules

Comment: @tsanchev Yeah, it will be good if they implement something about that.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create my own FixtureController that extends the original \yii\faker\FixtureController and introduces new public property with list of fixture folders:

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'fixture' => [
        'class' => 'app\commands\FixtureController',
        'fixtureConfig' => [
            [
                'templatePath' => '@tests/fixtures/templates',
                'fixtureDataPath' => '@tests/fixtures/data',
                'namespace' => 'app\tests\fixtures',
            ],
            [
                'templatePath' => '@app/modules/custom/project/tests/fixtures/templates',
                'fixtureDataPath' => '@app/modules/custom/project/tests/fixtures/data',
                'namespace' => 'app\modules\custom\project\tests\fixtures',
            ],
        ]
    ],
]
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace app\commands;

class FixtureController extends \yii\faker\FixtureController
{
    public $fixtureConfig = [];

    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        // This disables method beforeAction() only for CLI call of \app\commands\FixtureController::actionLoad()
        // The actionLoad() below is "manually" running parent::beforeAction() and parent::actionLoad() so beforeAction() is still executed correctly.
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Loads fixtures for multiple namespaces.
     */
    public function actionLoad(array $fixturesInput = [])
    {
        foreach ($this->fixtureConfig as $config) {
            $this->templatePath = $config['templatePath'];
            $this->fixtureDataPath = $config['fixtureDataPath'];
            $this->namespace = $config['namespace'];
            parent::beforeAction($this->action);
            parent::actionLoad($fixturesInput);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Unloads fixtures for multiple namespaces.
     */
    public function actionUnload(array $fixturesInput = [])
    {
        foreach ($this->fixtureConfig as $config) {
            $this->templatePath = $config['templatePath'];
            $this->fixtureDataPath = $config['fixtureDataPath'];
            $this->namespace = $config['namespace'];
            parent::beforeAction($this->action);
            parent::actionUnload($fixturesInput);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Generates fixtures for multiple namespaces.
    */
    public function actionGenerate(array $fixturesInput = [])
    {
        foreach ($this->fixtureConfig as $config) {
            $this->templatePath = $config['templatePath'];
            $this->fixtureDataPath = $config['fixtureDataPath'];
            $this->namespace = $config['namespace'];
            parent::beforeAction($this->action);
            parent::actionGenerate(...$fixturesInput);
        }
    }


}
```

Now you can run it like this:

```
php yii fixture/load "*"
```

I will paste it also to my 3 [Yii snippet guides](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2552/yii-v2-snippet-guide)